# Steps to run kafka connect on windows7?

Tags: apache-kafka, ibm-mq, apache-kafka-connect

I am able to setup and run kafka on windows7 as [mentioed](https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os), can you please help me with the steps to run the [mq-connector](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-mq-source) or other connector jar on windows. thanks in advance

Comment: It's totally different question, I don't find any steps in Google to run connector jar in standalone mode on windows..need help on this.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering to my own question, 
Here are the instructions to
[Setting Up and Running Apache Kafka on Windows7 OS](https://dzone.com/articles/running-apache-kafka-on-windows-os) and steps to run the [mq-connector](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-mq-source) jar or any other connector on windows.

```
>>CLASSPATH=<connector-root-directory>/target/kafka-connect-mq-source-0.2-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
>>bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties ~/mq-source.properties
```