# Not writing to log4j appender file?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, log4j, apache-kafka-connect

We are running kafka connector [java repo](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-mq-source)(executable JAR with dependencies using Maven) which connects kafka and ibm mq source we are running the jar build on windows/ linux machines and its running successfully.
[log4j.properties](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-mq-source/blob/master/src/test/resources/log4j.properties) as given but I modified to persist in log file as below

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender

log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\logigng.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

but its not writing anything to target file. What is the issue here? Is this required any code changes in the repo to make it write to log4j appender file?here is [POM file](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-mq-source/blob/master/pom.xml) for ref.does it required any precautions while building Maven jar-with dependencies via Eclipse(Oxyzen) IDE. Please help with log4j.properties file and steps to make it run in both windows/ unix. Thanks

Comment: You do have a typo on `C:\\logigng.log`

Comment: Even its typo file is not getting created with logigng.log. thanks

Comment: Where did you put your log4j.property file? It has to be at the classpath (to be 100% sure put at the very beginning of the classpath - otherwise it might be hidden by another log4j configuration).

Comment: We are putting log4j.properties in a src/test/resources(https://github.com/ibm-messaging/kafka-connect-mq-source/blob/master/src/test/resources/log4j.properties) location. Can you please help with example to put at begining of the classpath thanks

Comment: `src/main/resources` should work for you.

Comment: src/main/resources approach didn't worked.  Here are the steps I followed to run the jar in windows  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48314271/steps-to-run-kafka-connect-on-windows7/48854614#48854614